# Creating hive table on spark output on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have my Spark job which is running every 30 minutes and writing output to hdfs-`(/tmp/data/1497567600000)`. I have this job continuously running in the cluster. 
How can I create a Hive table on top of this data? I have seen one solution in StackOverFlow which creates a hive table on top of data partitioned by date field. which is like,

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mydb.mytable`
 (`col1` string, 
  `col2` decimal(38,0), 
  `create_date` timestamp, 
  `update_date` timestamp)
  PARTITIONED BY (`my_date` string)
  STORED AS ORC
  LOCATION '/tmp/out/'
```

and the solution suggests to Alter the table as,

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD PARTITION (my_date=20160101) LOCATION '/tmp/out/20160101'
```

But, in my case, I have no idea on how the output directories are being written, and so I clearly can't create the partitions as suggested above.

How can I handle this case, where the output directories are being randomly written in timestamp basis and is not in format (`/tmp/data/timestamp= 1497567600000`)?

How can I make Hive pick the data under the directory `/tmp/data`?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two solutions:

- If you can change your Spark job, then you can partition your data by hour (e.g. `/tmp/data/1`, `/tmp/data/2`), add Hive partitions for each hour and just write to relevant partition
- you can write bash script responsible for adding Hive partitions which can be achieved by:

  - listing HDFS subdirectories using command `hadoop fs -ls /tmp/data`
  - listing hive partitions for table using command: `hive -e 'show partitions table;'`
  - comparing above lists to find missing partitions
  - adding new Hive partitions with command provided above: `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD PARTITION (my_date=20160101) LOCATION '/tmp/out/20160101'`

Comment: Let me consider the second solution. Can you elaborate the answer please? I'm confused on how to create the table in this case to load the partitions.

Comment: You need to create partitions using comman provided in your question: `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD PARTITION (my_date=20160101) LOCATION '/tmp/out/20160101'`